# read value from property file inside xpath

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

Below First part is my code, i have to read my substring logic from xpath.But I dont want the above code to be in my camel context insead i want to read from property file, i wish i could do something like below in second part where substring logic is a key in property file. I am loading my property file from BrigePropertyPlaceholder by Spring.

```
    <xpath>starts-with(substring-after((/*/FullName/text()), 'Mr.'), "Xyz")
    </xpath>


    <camelContext> ....
    <xpath>{properties:substringlogic}</xpath>
    </camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<xpath>{{substringlogic}}</xpath>
```

See more details in the Camel docs: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Invalid xpath: {{logic}}. Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unexpected token "{" in path expression ********
 i get above error on using it

Comment: Hey Claus i had seen in one of your post you had mentioned that we can throw exception in Spring DSL as   :  <throwException exceptionType="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" message="Illegal argument passed"/> But this is not possible instead we have to pass ref in throwException which is not very flexible

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried with a newer version

Comment: I am using 2.17, and i remeber in one of your post https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4576 you have mentioned <throwException exceptionType="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" message="Darn ${body} is invalid"/>  is possible

Comment: You are out of scope of this question. This QA is about your original question.